# Scala Map, implict symbol key to string

Tags: string, scala, dictionary, symbols, implicit-conversion

**UPDATE**
All the answers are good here, but @senia's does so the most directly, without need for additional steps. Will this lead to bugs, possibly, but when using Map[Symbol, T] convention in hundreds of methods, a 1-step implicit conversion prior to map creation is preferred (avoids Symbol Map key permgen storage). At any rate, here's the pimp:

```
class SymbolProvidesPair(i: Symbol) { def ->[T](s: T) = (i.toString.tail, s) }
@inline implicit def symbol2String(i: Symbol) = new SymbolProvidesPair(i)
```

**Original**
It bothers me a bit using string keys in Maps, just slows me down and is, IMO, not as syntactically easy on the eyes as symbol keys.

```
val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("strings" -> 1, "blow" -> 2)
val map: Map[String, Int] = Map('symbols -> 1, 'rock -> 2)
```

So, I created an implicit to scratch my itch:

```
implicit def symbolKey2String[A <: Symbol, B](x:(A,B)) = (x._1.toString, x._2)
```

Couple things:
1) is this the correct signature? The above works, but `A <: Symbol` I take to mean, something that derives from Symbol vs. something that equals Symbol.

2) I'll be using this when I manually type out Maps; i.e. just for convenience. Am I going to hit any snags with this implicit? It seems edge case enough to not cause issues (like string2Int, for example), but not sure if I'm missing something.

Thanks

**EDIT**
Ok, well #1 I can just actually say what I mean, `[Symbol, B]` instead of `[A <: Symbol, B]`

But now I find myself with another issue, the symbol-to-string implicit boxes me into a corner of sorts as I then have to explicitly define Map[String, Type] for all new Maps (i.e. lose the nice compiler type inference) in order to be able to use symbol keys.

How then to get the best of both worlds, Map symbol keys, but with inferred [String, Type] when not specifying the type signature? i.e. have the compiler infer Map[String, Int] when I do:

```
val map = Map('foo -> 1)
```

Comment: hmmm, I guess I could just substitute "Symbol" for "A" ;-)

Comment: This kind of behavior could surprise other developers. Maybe it would be better to replace `->` with some other word? For example `:->` or `~>`.

Comment: I think in the context of Pimp-My-Library pattern (which is exactly the pattern provided in your answer), Symbol -> Type is perfectly fine. The nice thing about the Scala compiler is, anyone confused can hover their mouse over "->" to click through and see the implicit. In Ruby, Groovy, etc., much more of a magical mystery tour without explicit documentation. Also, Symbol Map keys take up permgen, so their apparent use should raise some eyebrows (and investigation). Finally, the compiler will infer Map[String, Type], so that as well should lead one to find out how it's happening

Comment: I agree with @senia. You are changing the meaning of `'sym -> 1`. Pimp-my-library is more about adding, not changing. Plus, you may find youself in trouble if you really wanted a map with Symbol as a key.

Comment: does it not defeat the purpose of symbol if you have to create a new string on every implicit conversion?

Comment: @Dragonborn depends on your use case, I'm using symbols just for concision/readability. Also, the implicit is scoped to my model layer (i.e. only using for Play form mappings) so performance impact is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to specify map's type explicitly:

```
scala> class SymbolToPait(i: Symbol) { def ->[T](s: T) = (i.toString().tail, s)}
defined class SymbolToPait

scala> implicit def symbolToPair(i: Symbol) = new SymbolToPait(i)
symbolToPair: (i: Symbol)SymbolToPait

scala> 'Symbol -> "String"
res0: (String, String) = (Symbol,String)

scala> Map('Symbol -> "String")
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Symbol -> String)

scala> Map('Symbol -> 1)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Symbol -> 1)
```

This kind of behavior could surprise other developers. Maybe it would be better to replace `->` with some other word? For example `:->` or `~>`.

Comment: totally sick, dude ;-) pimp-my-library to boot, so the case is isolated/safe. Are you using this yourself, or just whipped this off? Any drawbacks to account for/be aware of?

Comment: I'm learning scala for about 2 or 3 weeks, so I have no favorite tricks yet. And I'm not a native English speaker, so it's difficult for me to understand some parts of your comment.

Comment: sorry, "totally sick, dude" means something like, "thanks, great answer!" I implemented the pattern and indeed it works, compiler infers symbol keys as strings without need to specify the signature. Impressive, if you are learning Scala for 2 or 3 weeks, I want to see where you are after 1 year ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, there is no need for `A`. You probably want to drop the first character as well, which is always a `'`

```
implicit def symbolKeyToString[B](x: (Symbol, B)) = (x._1.toString.tail, x._2)
```

As for snags, well, you have to type out the signature of the map every time, and your keys can't contain spaces or operator characters. This is not something I would do myself...

Edit: if you don't want to type out the signature each time, use an alternative to `Map.apply` and forget implicits:

```
object Map2 {
  def apply[B](xs: (Symbol, B)*) = 
    xs map {case (k, v) => (k.toString.tail, v)} toMap
}
```

Comment: +1, good point, did not know the ' was preserved as part of the key! That was the next bit, I realized, oh no, now I have to explicitly type out the Map signature, which kind of defeats the purpose. Anyway to get the compiler to infer Map[String, Type] when using symbol keys?

Comment: Interesting with alternative Map.apply. The nice thing about pimp-my-library is, I can drop the implicit into a package object and not have to do any importing, plus, it should be completely safe (i.e. I don't ever intend to use Map[Symbol, Type] based on the permgen issue alone)

Comment: @virtualeyes This `Map2` can be defined in your package as well, so that's no disadvantage to using implicits. With @senia's answer you are quietly overriding the implicit `any2ArrowAssoc` from Predef for Symbols, which can lead to bugs if you forget about it.

Comment: Just tried it, works, but Map2, that's not so appealing ;-) You are right, I see now that any2ArrowAssoc is indeed overridden. In what cases could this lead to bugs? The only place where Symbols are a must-have is with Map keys, so the implicit conversion to String is very welcome. Given that Symbols are apparently permgen-stored I'm not too keen on using them in the first place (unless I can convert them prior to storage)

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple of warnings about the current solutions.

First of all, you're changing the meaning of `'sym -> x`, and it will mean something different from `('sym, x)`. I would find this confusing.

You also make it difficult to mix code that uses this conversion with code that actually needs `Map[Symbol, _]`.

Instead of converting the symbols to strings before putting them into a map, I recommend just converting the map. Seems much more straightforward to me.

```
scala> implicit def symMap2strMap[T](m: Map[Symbol, T]): Map[String, T] = m.map {
     |   case (key, value) => key.toString.tail -> value
     | }
symMap2strMap: [T](m: Map[Symbol,T])scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,T]

scala> val sym = Map('foo -> 1, 'bar -> 2)
sym: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Symbol,Int] = Map('foo -> 1, 'bar -> 2)

scala> sym: Map[String, Int]
res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(foo -> 1, bar -> 2)
```

*Edit*:

You should never have to specify the type to explicitly convert `Map[Symbol, T]` to `Map[String, T]`. Just leave it as a `Map[Symbol, T]` until you hit an API which requires string keys, then let Scala implicitly convert it to the type you want.

Comment: whoops, hang on, that's not what I want ;-) It's likely a minor-issue, but Map Symbol keys take up permgen; @senia's solution makes the conversion from Symbol to String prior to (or during) Map creation, which gives Map[String, T] as the result. Also, I definitely don't want to manually convert the map post-creation. I'll be using Map[Symbol, T] convention in hundreds of controller methods, will drive me nuts having to specify the "real" type. May get bitten, true, we'll see, seems way more edge casey than string2Int or other guaranteed-future-bug

Comment: @virtualeyes Not sure about the whole PermGen issue. Are the symbols stored in PermGen? How does converting before putting into the map help? About specifying the real type, you should never have to do that. Will update answer.

Comment: missed that, the implicit conversion at work ;-) Need to research this more, Symbols are auto intern'd; as a result, they go into permgen. senia's solution would appear to convert the Symbol to String prior to Map creation, whereas your solution is on-demand conversion (I wonder if in fact an entirely new Map is then created?). I'll give you the nod if there's evidence that proves your approach will not incur any permgen overhead...

Comment: @virtualeyes I would be surprised if PermGen consumption is different, since you still have the same number of symbols in both cases; you're only changing where you convert them. Still good to test, though. Results should be interesting.

Comment: yes, I'm curious as well. It all depends on when Symbol storage occurs; if it occurs prior to senia's implicit Symbol-to-String conversion, then, both your approach and his/hers are equal (and yours safer). I'd like to think that Symbol storage occurs on assignment to val/var/def and not prior to the implicit conversion...but that's just what I want it to be, not necessarily the reality ;-)